# How to remove google ads virus from IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, virus-removal, adware

I have picked up adware in that shows extra irrelevant google ads. This only happens in Internet Explorer 10, not Firefox or Iron. I have tried some removals for similar viruses with no luck. I have scanned with MalwareBytes, Windows Defender(I am using Windows 8 RTM, so this is the same as MSE), Spybot, Ad Aware, McAfee, Norton, and AVG, with no luck. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, ads are added to the tan area as well as several extra white results, which are especially irrelevant. I like IE10 and would like to keep using it, but these ads are annoying. I'm also worried there may be spyware as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that some add on called "DealCabby" was causing this. I used [Everything Search](http://www.voidtools.com/) to find and delete all files with the name "DealCabby" in them, and I am now ad free.

Comment: So how did DealCabby get installed?

Comment: I honestly can't remember. Probably was my fault though